# Calling a Windows Calculator in a GWT web application

Tags: java, gwt, processbuilder

When I click the calculator button in my GWT application its trying to call the External Windows Calculator (External webapps). I used to achieve this on **ProcessBuilder** class in java side.

But i will not able to do it. i have seen one post in stackoverflow similar problem like what i am facing now [Post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208579/calling-an-external-application-i-e-windows-calculator-in-a-gwt-web-applicati). There i could not see any solution for that problem thats why i am rising again.

Anybody know How to call the external windows calculator from GWT application?

Comment: The two highest voted answers both say: "You cannot do it".

Comment: Yeah but it should have some way to achieve. thats i need

Comment: Just because you need it doesn't mean that it's possible...

Comment: I stick to my answer :p

Comment: The duplicate question actually *has* possible solutions to your problem - ActiveXObject in IE or via a Java Applet. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: @lgor Klimer No i didnt tried. Could you please give me the sample snippet..

Comment: @saravanakumar: please do some research yourself. A quick search will get you the code needed (I checked). If you'll have some more problems with running the code, *then* please ask a new question and someone will surely help. But please show that you are trying to solve the problem yourself, don't just ask for everything to be handed to you on a plate. You won't learn anything that way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, by design. If you really, really, really need to, you can ask the user to install some registry fixes that allow you to use the calculator as a custom URI protocol (such as calc://), but that raises so many flags (also in the browser, when you use that link) that it's not worth it.

More to the point: What are you trying to achieve with this? Why do you want to be able to do it?

Comment: Its not like that. We are using our own calculator which is designed in GWT but its not working correctly and instead of trying to create new one, why dont we use existing apps. Thats our main intention and also will save the time.